# Structure of subgroups of direct products

Tags: group-theory, direct-product

**Goursat's Lemma**: Let $A$ and $B$ be groups. There is a bijective correspondence between the subgroups of $A\times B$ and the set of quintuples $(G_1,G_2,H_1,H_2,\varphi)$ where $G_2\unlhd G_1\leq A$, $H_2\unlhd H_1\leq B$ and $\varphi: G_1/G_2\to H_1/H_2$ is an isomorphism.

So assuming that $U \leq A\times B$ and letting $G_1 = \pi_A(U)$, $H_1 = \pi_B(U)$, $ G_2 = i_A(U)$ and $H_2 = i_B(U)$, where $i_X: X \to A\times B$ for $X = A, B$, the inclusion map, we obtain that $U$ determines the quintuples

> Conversely, given a quintuple $(G_1,G_2,H_1,H_2,\varphi)$ where $G_2\unlhd G_1\leq A$, $H_2\unlhd H_1\leq B$ and $\varphi: G_1/G_2\to H_1/H_2$ is an isomorphism, how can I determine the converse of this bijective correspondence stated in Goursat's Lemma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The corresponding subgroup is $\{ (x,y) : x \in G_1, y \in H_1, y \in \phi(x)H_2 \}$.

Comment: Okay I have managed to show it is a subgroup of $ A \times B$. Would this be sufficient to say that there is bijective correspondence between the set $S$ consisting of all subgroups of $A\times B$ and $T$ the set of all quintuples $(G1, G_2, H1, H2)$ as defined above? because I have not actually defined a function between the sets

Comment: @RMaharaj Yes, you have defined the function between them now. In one direction in your question and the other direction as given in this answer.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks. However, from what gage, I have only defined $f : S \to T$ by $f(U) = ( G_{1_U}, G_{2_U}, H_{1_U}, H_{2_U}, \varphi_U)$  for some subgroup $U$ of $ A \times B$.. Need I not show that this is bijective?

Comment: @RMaharaj This answer gives you the inverse.